# Цикл в shell повторяет одну и ту же итерацию

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Написал скрипт для конвертации и последующей склейки видео в shell. Он должен проходить по папкам и в каждой проводить операции над файлами, но почему-то когда он доходит до последнего файла цикл не заходит в следующую папку, а начинает заново работать в той же самой папке.

```
for d in ${dir}*
do
    cd ${dir}
    video_folder=${d:23:8}
    echo "Check ${dir}${video_folder}"
    if [[ -d ${video_folder} ]]
    then
        for f in ${video_folder}/*
        do
            if [[ -f ${f} ]]
            then
                file_extension=${f##*.}
                echo "file_extension = $file_extension"
                echo "extension = $extension"
                if [ $file_extension == $extension ]
                then
                    echo "Convert avi to mpg ${f}"
                    ffmpeg -i ${f} -c copy -y ${f}.mpg
                    #rm -f ${d}${f}
                fi
            fi
        done
        echo "Concat mpg to mp4"
        ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in *.mpg; do echo "file '$f'"; done) -c copy -y xx.mp4
    fi
done
```

Причем ошибка появляется только на строке:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in *.mpg; do echo "file '$f'"; done) -c copy -y xx.mp4
```

но ее я уже понял как решить. Проблема в том, что даже без этой строки цикл постоянно повторяется.

Comment: `for d in ${dir}*` — сработает столько раз, сколько у вас есть файлов/каталогов, имя которых начинается с содержимого переменной `dir`. если в ней, например, `/tmp/x`, а у вас есть файлы/каталоги `/tmp/x`, `/tmp/xy`, `/tmp/xуz`, то цикл выполнится три раза. // а вообще написано очень запутанно. постарайтесь писать более человекочитаемый код. в частности, описывая желаемое поведение в комментариях. это, между прочим, и неплохо дисциплинирует, и ускоряет разработку, и облегчает чтение кода как другим, так и себе самому по прошествию времени.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте организовать цикл через find:

1) Ошибка в вашем коде, скорее всего, заключается в том, что зайдя в папку 
`cd ${d}` после ее обработки Вы не выходите назад `cd ..`

2) `video_folder=${d:23:8}` у меня возникло ощущение, что таким образом Вы хотели получить имя папки после '/'. Присмотритесь к функциям `basename` и `dirname`

3) Имхо `find` для этой задачи удобнее

**UPD:**

После вдумчивого омысления получилось следующее:

```
extension=avi
dvr_video_dir="$HOME/dvr_video" # К примеру

find "$dvr_video_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -regex "^${dvr_video_dir}$" | \
while read -r working_dir; do
    find "$working_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.$extension" | \
    while read -r video_file;do
        # file_extension=${video_file##*.}
        # filename="$(basename "$video_file" | sed -r "s/.${file_extension}$//")"
        filename="${video_file##*\/}" && filename=${filename%.*}
        echo "Convert ${filename}.avi to ${filename}.mpg in $working_dir"
        if ffmpeg \
            -i "${video_file}" \
            -c copy \
            -y "${working_dir}/${filename}.mpg" # Я не совсем в теме как че с ffmpeg но умный IDE, в данном случае, предложил закончить строчку < /dev/null
        then
            rm "${video_file}" # Если хотите чтобы оригиналы удалялись в случае успешной конвертации
        else
            read -r -p "Fail converting ${video_file}. Continue? : " -i 'n' -e REPLAY
            [[ "${REPLAY}" == 'n' || -z "${REPLAY}" ]] && exit 1
        fi
    done
    # concatenated_mp4_file_name="$(basename "$working_dir")"
    concatenated_mp4_file_name="${working_dir##*\/}}"
    echo "Concat mpg to mp4"
    mapfile -t mpeg_files <<<"$(find "$working_dir" \
                                    -maxdepth 1 \
                                    -type f \
                                    -name '*.mpg')"

            [[ -n "${mpeg_files[*]}" ]] && \
        echo "Concat mpg to mp4 in $working_dir" && \
        if ffmpeg \
            -f concat \
            -i "${mpeg_files[@]}" \
            -c copy \
            -y "${working_dir}/${concatenated_mp4_file_name}.mp4" # Я не совсем в теме как че с ffmpeg но умный IDE, в данном случае, предложил закончить строчку < /dev/null
        then
            rm "${mpeg_files[@]}" # Если хотите, чтобы файлы из которых собирается mp4 тоже удалялись
        else
            read -r -p "Fail concatenation ${concatenated_mp4_file_name}.mp4. Continue? : " -i 'n' -e REPLAY
            [[ "${REPLAY}" == 'n' || -z "${REPLAY}" ]] && exit 1
        fi
done
```

Работу ffmpeg не проверял (хотя надо было потестить) но уж дюже гиморойно искать нарезку авишек, сори.

Comment: `find ... -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file` чтобы не было ошибок с пробелами

Comment: Для того, чтобы не было ошибок с пробелами, достаточно внутри цикла использовать "$file" но это не убережет от ошибок связанных с ! в именах файлов и папок. При обработке имен файлов взятых непонятно откуда вообще лучше использовать `printf '%q'`

Comment: На счёт первого посмотрю завтра, когда на работе буду. Во втором нет, там названия файлов состоят из даты и времени. Я использую дату для папок (в общем это не особо важно). Спасибо большое, завтра буду проверять. Просто вдруг но с того, ни с сего цикл не начинает новую итерацию, что ввело в ступор

Comment: @vovagib Относительно новой итерации... Вы переходите в папку с файлами `cd ${dir}` а вот обратного перехода `cd ..`, после выполнения действий над файлами в одной из директорий, я в Вашем коде не обнаружил. Посему очень вероятно, что скрипт не находит следующую папку

Comment: @vovagib добавил код

Comment: @vovagib И еще один вопрос. А нельзя их в один проход из avi сразу в 1 mp4 заделать. Имхо будет быстрее и какчественнее :-)

Comment: @TotalPusher, *man xargs*, чтобы проблем с пробелами и не только не было.

Comment: Shell — очень сложный язык программирования. Например, напишите в шапку *#!/bin/sh -efu*. Во-вторых, не используйте внешние команды там, где это не надо, например, получение имени файла или каталога. В-третьих, не используйте внешние команды в конвейере, когда эта функциональность уже имеется в предыдущей. Почитайте документацию в общем на *sh*, на *basename*... Ну и так далее. ВДУМЧИВО.

Comment: @0andriy Если не сложно, ткните пальцем в то, о чем Вы вот здесь "В-третьих, не используйте внешние команды в конвейере, когда эта функциональность уже имеется в предыдущей"

Comment: *basename* умеет обрезать т.н. расширение файла, но и эта команда там лишняя, используйте *#,##,%,%%* шаблоны прямо в переменных.

Comment: Спасибо, по делу ,-)

Comment: Ну и в целом, расширение у файла — это миф. Чтобы найти все видеофайлы определённого формата, необходимо получить их mime-type каким-то образом. В некотором приближении это умеет делать команда *file*.

Comment: И если уж быть совсем педантичным, то надо отличать форматы видео от контейнеров. Формата видео *AVI* не существует — это контейнер.

Comment: По первому согласен полностью, но "не дорос" пока )) По второму я вообще с видео дальше плеера не залезал ))

Comment: Дорастёте, если будете изучать. Удачи!

Comment: @0andriy, прошу прощения, перепутал ваши ответы с @AndreyKarpov по поводу `find | ...`

Comment: @TotalPusher, бывает. *... | while read x; do* защищает от пробельных символов в именах, но не защищает от многих других, как то перевода строки.